# SharePoint Documents after employee leaves

Tags: 2013, my-site, retention

We currently have a SharePoint 2013 farm, with an Active Directory User Profile sync, where we store public documents by department, in their own site collections by department, as well as personal documents in their own MySite Document Library.

When an employee leaves the company, we have been told that the documents of the former employee would be under the control of the Manager listed in Active Directory, after their account is deleted.

Is this true?  My concern, especially with the MySite documents, since they are in their own site collection would be lost after the cleanup removes the former employee's site.

Is there a best practice to ensure documents owned by a former employee are not purged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only partial true.

The Statements you made were to General. The System only applies to the MySite of the Employee. The Default behavior is to grant the manager 2 weeks of access to the mysite before it will be deleted.

Details Can be seen here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/06/25/inside-the-sharepoint-2010-my-site-cleanup-timer-job/ WARNING: Read the "You are on the clock section"

Some companies disable this behavior.

Any Documents in all other sites will not be touched by this.